# Calculate the edge coordinates of the dom element after transform the dom element using css rotateX, rotateY, perspective

Tags: javascript, css, image-processing, geometry

I use rotateX, rotateY, perspective to achieve the effect of transform elements.

I use getBoundingClientRect() to get the top, left, bottom, right, width, height of the element.

How to calculate the four vertices coordinate of the (dom element) after the image is transform.

sorry my enlish is bad

video demo:https://i.imgur.com/YYArUMz.mp4

image demo:

[image]

[image: calculate image coordinate]

Comment: might not be queryable. you might have to figure out how CSS defines these transforms, and then do the calculations yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`Element.getBoundingClientRect` considers the current CSS/SVG transform([CSSOM View Module](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/cssom-view/#dom-element-getclientrects:%7E:text=Apply%20the%20transforms%20that%20apply%20to%20the%20element%20and%20its%20ancestors.)). See it for yourself, while transform is changing, the return value of `getBoundingClientRect` will also change.

To query the screen position of transformed element's 4 corners, you have to add measurer children elements to the transformed element. After that, set the style of the measurer children as following:

```css
.measurer {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.measurer.top {
  top: 0;
}
.measurer.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
.measurer.left {
  left: 0;
}
.measurer.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

After that, you can do the `getBoundingClientRect` on the 4 measurer elements to get their position.